# Apache authentication for multiple directories

Tags: apache-2.2

I've website running in apache 2.2.3. Root directory of website contains three directories. I want to setup authentication for these directories as below

1. only user1 can browse all pages
2. user2 can only access mydomain.com/dir1/
3. user3 can only access mydomain.com/dir2/
4. user4 can only access mydomain.com/dir3/

I've tried below configuration but only user1 can browse website other users are unable to access website.

```
<directory /var/www/html/example>
        AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/user1-htpasswd
        AuthName "Resricted"
        AuthType Basic
        Require user user1
</directory>

<directory /var/www/html/example/dir1/>
        AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/user2-htpasswd
        AuthName "Resricted"
        AuthType Basic
        Require user user2
</directory>

<directory /var/www/html/example/dir2/>
        AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/user3-htpasswd
        AuthName "Resricted"
        AuthType Basic
        Require user user3
</directory>
```

Please guide me for the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you put all your users login info in one passwd file and then do something like this (untested)

```
<directory /var/www/html/example/dir1/>
        AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/users-htpasswd
        AuthName "Resricted"
        AuthType Basic
        Require user user1
        Require user user2
</directory>

<directory /var/www/html/example/dir2/>
        AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/users-htpasswd
        AuthName "Resricted"
        AuthType Basic
        Require user user1
        Require user user3
</directory>
```

Comment: You dont need multiple require user lines, you can "Require user user1 user2"

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled over this question and want to add:

Usually you don't want to list all users in the [require statement](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#require)

> Require user user 1...user x

either use

> Require valid-user

if you list all users anyway or add the users to a group

> Require group myGroup

For that you add the statement

> [AuthGroupFile](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_groupfile.html#authgroupfile) /your/path/groupFile

The content of *groupFile* is something like:

> myGroup: user1 user2 user3

Comment: There is no way to use: Require valid-user if you want diffent users on different folders